# load_dataset('multi_nli') from dataset is not working, getting import error

Tags: python, nlp, dataset

I am currently working on an NLI project, and about a week ago, load_dataset('multi_nli') was working just fine. However, when I was about to import it again and test a different model, an import error is showing up.

ImportError: cannot import name 'setup_logging' from 'fsspec.utils' (/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fsspec/utils.py)

Everything should be installed, like datasets and such but it is not working.

Comment: It is possible to import the dataset in Google Colab but on Kaggle it is giving me the ImportError

Comment: found out that fsspec needed an upgrade as the Kaggle uses the default version. !pip install --upgrade fsspec fixed the issue

Answer (score 3):

Ran into the same issue in a kaggle notebook.
For me the solution was uninstalling `s3fs` which was the package that caused the import of `fsspec` in the first place. So just add this in a cell at the beginning of your kaggle notebook.

```
!pip3 install datasets
!pip3 uninstall fsspec
```

Comment: This worked for me on kaggle notebooks `!pip uninstall fsspec -y` and 
`!pip install fsspec==2021.5.0`

Comment: @user3476359 Your answer saved me a lot of time in a Kaggle Competition :-)